# Curvature of a curve on a surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curvature

I dont know how to solve this problem in Do Carmo's Differential geometry of Curves and Surfaces. Can anyone help me?

Let $C$ be a **regular** curve on a surface $S$ with Gaussian curvature $K>0$ and principle curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$. Show that the curvature $k$ of $C$ at $p$ satisfies: $k\ge min\{|k_1|,|k_2|\}$.

Do I have to use the normal curvature to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you also add the definition of curvature of a curve in your question?

Comment: Conceptually, the best way to understand it is by thinking about normal curvature, yes, since that's the meaning of the principal curvatures.

Comment: the definition is the same do carmo is using in differential geometry. you find the problem at p. 153!

Comment: so i think you should assume that the curve is parametrised by arc length. then the curvature of the curve is defined by: $|c''(s)|=k(s)$

Comment: @JadonD87 I just want to point out that it would be unclear to me which curvatures you are referring to when $S$ is an abstract surface. (I was confused because you are so certain that Narasimham's answer is not what you want, while his answer looks good to me. Indeed, another answer is essentially along the same line)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you have to use the normal curvature. Because of
\begin{equation}\kappa^2=\kappa_g^2+\kappa_n^2
\end{equation}
it is sufficient to prove $\kappa_n\geq \min \{k_1,k_2\}$, where $\kappa_g, \kappa_n$ denote the geodesic and normal curvature. 
From now on we may assume that the curve $c:I\to S$ is parametrised by arc length. Therefore we can write (at $t_0$ arbitrary) $c'=\cos(\alpha) w_1 + \sin(\alpha) w_2$ for some angle $\alpha.$ Then
\begin{equation}\kappa_n=\langle c'', \nu\circ c \rangle= -\langle c',(d\nu)(c')\rangle=II(c',c')
\end{equation}
and by using the bilinearity of the second fundamental form we get (depending on the sign convention of the principal curvatures)
\begin{equation}II(c',c')=\cos(\alpha)^2 k_1 + \sin(\alpha)^2 k_2
\end{equation}
We can choose $\nu$ in such a way that $k_1,k_2>0$. Furthermore we may assume $k_1\geq k_2.$ Putting everything together we obtain
\begin{equation}\kappa\geq \kappa_n=II(c',c')=\cos(\alpha)^2 k_1 + \sin(\alpha)^2 k_2\geq \cos(\alpha)^2 k_2 + \sin(\alpha)^2k_2=k_2=\min\{k_1,k_2\}.
\end{equation}

Comment: thanks for the answer! it's probably right, but we didn't talk about geodesic curvature yet in out course. and do carmo didn't do so, too, at the point, where he is introducing the problem: do carmo, differential geometry, p. 153. do you have another idea?

Comment: The only important thing is $\kappa_n^2\leq \kappa^2,$ which you can prove without using geodesic curvature by $\kappa^2=\Vert c''\Vert^2\geq \Vert (c'')^{\text{normal}}\Vert^2=\kappa_n^2$

Comment: what do you mean by $(c'') ^{normal}$?

Comment: Every vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^3=T_pS\oplus \mathbb{R}\nu(p)$ can be written as $v=v^{\text{tang.}}+v^{\text{normal}},$ where $v^{\text{normal}}=\langle v, \nu(p)\rangle$ is the normal\perpendicular part of the vector $v$ and $v^{\text{tang.}}$ is the tangential part.

Answer (score 2):

I  think you wanted to ask

Show that the normal curvature $k_n$ of $C$ at $p$ satisfies:

$$k_n \ge min\{|k_1|,|k_2|\}$$

$$k_n \le max\{|k_1|,|k_2|\}$$

Or

$$ |k_1|>  k_n >| k_2|$$

This comes out of Euler scalar normal curvature identity by finding  max/min values by differentiation.

$$ k_n = k_1 cos^2 \theta + k_2 sin^2 \theta $$
Where $\theta$ is angle curve makes to direction 1.

EDIT1
If at all another curvature is to be brought in, that is geodesic torsion$ \tau_g$ rather than $ k_g$ included in the Mohr Circle.. and makes more clear their magnitudes geometrically.

[image: MohrCircle]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but no, the problem is exactly like what i have written

Comment: Corrected a typo..

Comment: no, that is not what i have to show

Answer (score 2):

The normal curvature, by Euler's formula is
$$k_n (\theta) = k_1 \cos^2 \theta + k_2 \sin^2 \theta$$
Also, by definition we have that normal curvature is $k_n = k \cos \theta$. Since curvature $k>0$ so $|k|=k$. We also use the fact $|\cos \theta| \leq 1$.

By hypotesis $K = k_1 \cdot k_2 >0$ and then the principal curvatures must be either both positive of both negative. So $k_1, k_2$ having the same sign means that we will never have to deal with $\pm k_1 \cos^2 \theta \mp k_2 \sin^2 \theta$.

Therefore

$$k = |k| \geq |k \cos \theta| = |k_n| = \pm k_n = \pm(k_1 \cos^2 \theta + k_2 \sin^2 \theta) = \pm k_1 \cos^2 \theta \pm k_2 \sin^2 \theta = |k_1| \cos^2 \theta + |k_2| \sin^2 \theta \geq \min \{|k_1|,|k_2|\} \cos^2 \theta + \min \{|k_1|,|k_2|\} \sin^2 \theta = \min \{|k_1|,|k_2|\}.$$